# Running multiple Elasticsearch production nodes in one machine

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it a recommended practice to run multiple Elasticsearch nodes in one physical (virtual) machine? I'm speaking about production environment.

I currently have three virtual machines that unicast each other. Setup:

```
node.name:"VM1"
master:true
data:true

node.name:"VM2"
master:true
data:true

node.name:"VM3"
master:false
data:true
```

There's a request to have a dedicated master node in first virtual machine (next to VM1). I'm trying to avoid that and looking for strong arguments that I shouldn't do this.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a dedicated master makes sense in a larger environment to me. I would say if your nodes are not that busy having a data node also be a master would not be the end of the world. I would be more comfortable having 3 data nodes for high availability.

Comment: My current index size is about 2gb only with a growth potential (excluding replicas). Plus monthly logs collected for Marvel. What if my VM goes down and takes both dedicated master and VM1 down? How should I configure `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` then?

Comment: I would be okay with what you have now. In fact I would make all three nodes acting as both data and master. When you see growth you can always change this up. We have a cluster of around 60 nodes and have 3 dedicated masters. Two master nodes can leave you open to split brain syndrome.

Comment: How shall I set up `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes`? Currently this parameter has a value of `2` in my configuration. If master node goes down. Won't it cause issues?

Comment: Put this at 2 and have all 3 data nodes act as master as well. Unless you increase the number of VM's I don't really see another option.